# Is there any reason to use multiple mdraids instead of just one with multiple partitions?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Everywhere I look people seem to recommend using multiple mdraids. E.g. one for /boot, one for swap, and one for /.

I do understand that you can spread the load over different drives for different tasks, but is that the only reason? Is a separate mdraid for /boot only required if UEFI isn't used? Are there any downsides to just using one mdraid that contains both swap and root when you just have a couple of drives?

So, in what situations are multiple mdraids needed or a better solution?

Comment: Cite your sources.  What is your definition of "mdraids"?  Are you talking about partitions?  Where in 2020 are you seeing people recommend a separate partition for `/boot` and `swap`?  There are only downsides, and no positives to having either one of these on separate partitions.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of information around partitioning and RAID setup are based on opinion, requirements specific to a use-case, or outdated information.

Addressing a few of your specific points:

- I personally don't see a need to have a separate array for `/boot`.  It is true that Grub used to not be able to read your kernel off a `/boot` located on a mdadm created array but that is no longer the case.  I say this having this exact setup for a non-EFI booting server.
- I would *never* put a swap partition on a mdadm created array.  Under practically all circumstances, swap never needs redundant disks.  If you're looking at RAID-0, you can just stripe swap across multiple disks.

As a side note, mdadm schedules monthly disk checks and I'm not sure it's smart enough to not schedule simultaneous checks if the arrays use the same backing disk.